# Node group not found after script execution

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, add-on, compositing-nodes

I was trying to recreate script from video, but with my own node group and I ended up with an Error which is too hard for me to understand. Script did works and create node groupe, but for some reason that I can't understand do not adding it properly to the worrking space, it just added node groupe that's called "Missing Data-Block" and then I need to select a newly created group by hand (It must be selected by default).

Image:
[image]

Script:

```
import bpy

class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custome Compositing Node"
    bl_idname = "MainPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Custom nodes"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('node.pixelazer_operator')


def create_pixelazer_group_node(context, operator, group_name):
    bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True      #enable "Use nodes" in compositing tab

    pixelazer_group_node = bpy.data.node_groups.new(group_name, 'CompositorNodeTree')

    group_in = pixelazer_group_node.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')     #inputs
    group_in.location = (-300,0)
    pixelazer_group_node.inputs.new('NodeSocketImage', 'Image')
    pixelazer_group_node.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat','Pixelazed strength')

    group_out = pixelazer_group_node.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')   #outputs
    group_out.location = (800,0)
    pixelazer_group_node.outputs.new('NodeSocketImage','Pixelated image')

    blur_node = pixelazer_group_node.nodes.new(type= 'CompositorNodeBlur') #adding new nodes
    blur_node.location = (-100,250)
    blur_node.size_x = 5
    blur_node.size_y = 5

    first_math_node = pixelazer_group_node.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeMath')
    first_math_node.location = (-100, 0)
    first_math_node.operation = 'DIVIDE'
    first_math_node.inputs[0].default_value = 1

    first_scale_node = pixelazer_group_node.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeScale')
    first_scale_node.location = (100, 250)

    pixelate_node = pixelazer_group_node.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodePixelate')

    pixelate_node.location = (300, 250)

    second_scale_node = pixelazer_group_node.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeScale')
    second_scale_node.location = (500, 250)

    #links connections
    link = pixelazer_group_node.links.new

    link(group_in.outputs[0],blur_node.inputs[0])    #connecting input node
    link(group_in.outputs[1], first_math_node.inputs[1])
    link(group_in.outputs[1], second_scale_node.inputs[1])
    link(group_in.outputs[1], second_scale_node.inputs[2])

    link(blur_node.outputs[0], first_scale_node.inputs[0])    #connecting blur node and scale node
    link(first_math_node.outputs[0], first_scale_node.inputs[1])  #connecting math node and scale node (to change scale by x)
    link(first_math_node.outputs[0], first_scale_node.inputs[2])  #connecting math node and scale node (to change scale by y)

    link(first_scale_node.outputs[0], pixelate_node.inputs[0])    #connecting first scale node and pixelate node
    link(pixelate_node.outputs[0], second_scale_node.inputs[0])   #connecting pixelata node and second scale node

    link(second_scale_node.outputs[0], group_out.inputs[0])  #connecting pixelata node and second scale node

    return pixelate_node

class NODE_OT_PIXELATE(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Pixelazer Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.pixelazer_operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        custom_node_name = "Pixelazer Node"
        my_group = create_pixelazer_group_node(self, context, custom_node_name)
        pixelazer_node = context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')
        pixelazer_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
        pixelazer_node.use_custom_color = True
        pixelazer_node.color = (0.5,0.1,0.7)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_PIXELATE)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_PIXELATE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Error says:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\CustomeCompositingNodeGroups.py", line 78, in execute
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Pixelate" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the *Pixelate* node in your creation method. You want to return the *Group* node.

Replace line 68 :

```
return pixelate_node
```

with

```
return pixelazer_group_node
```

Result :

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't know one could add an image into a group node input !

Comment: Thank you alot!